# use ggplot2 to plot two lines with ribbons

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I have a data frame with a metric v and a categorical variable t.
I can plot them as lines like this

```
set.seed(42)
v <- runif(20, min=0, max=100)
t <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 20, replace=TRUE )

df <- data.frame(v,t)

qplot(1:length(v),v,data=df,geom="line",group=t,color=t)
```

I'd like to add ribbons around each line. Possibly of different width (that I'll set with a formula) and transparency. I tried to replace the geom with "ribbon" but I get the following error:

```
qplot(1:length(v),v,data=df,geom="ribbon",group=t,color=t)
Error: geom_ribbon requires the following missing aesthetics: ymin, ymax
```

How can I plot both lines and their ribbons in one chart?

Comment: The ribbon needs a lower and upper limit, but you haven't provided these. What do you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you can add a ribbon. You can, of course, change the formulas for `ymin` and `ymax` to suit your needs:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=1:length(v), y=v, group=t, colour=t)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=v-0.1*v, ymax=v+0.1*v, fill=t), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: I was thinking that you'd want the line after the ribbon so that it wouldn't be "covered" by the ribbon in cases where alpha=1.

Comment: That was just an error in my code--I put the `+` in the wrong place. Fixed now.

Comment: It is true that if the line and ribbon fill are the same color and alpha, then you won't see the line regardless of the plotting order. However, you can set a different color and/or alpha for the lines and the ribbon fill in order to remedy this. Either way, if you want the line "on top" you need to plot it after the ribbon.